# spring boot validation of request parameters - @NotNull is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I am trying to add Validation for my request parameters of my rest endpoint. I see that @NotBlank is working as expected and throwing Constraint violation exception while @NotNull is not.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @Validated
    class MyController{
    
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Data> getData(
             @RequestParam @NotNull(message = "age is required") Integer age,
             @RequestParam @NotBlank(message = "name is required") String name){
              
             //do something  
         }
    }
```

Dependency Used :  implementation **'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'**

when I try to hit following endpoints from my postman to test this,

http://localhost:8080/myApp/test/data?age=&name='myname' - doesn't throw constraintviolationexception

http://localhost:8080/myApp/test/data?age=null&name='myname' - doesn't throw constraintviolationexception

http://localhost:8080/myApp/test/data?name='myname' - doesn't throw constraintviolationexception

http://localhost:8080/myApp/test/data?age=22&name='' - throws constraintviolationexception

java version used : Java 17
spring boot version : 2.7.7

Any Idea what I might be missing ?

Comment: Did you use the proper `@NotNull`?

Comment: yes I am using javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

Comment: Try to use also @Valid annotation

Comment: @Wikimmax Yeah even tried that adding before requestparam but it didn't work.

Comment: I would suggest to simply create a wrapper class which would bind the parameters instead of using query parameters. That way you can annotate the fields in that class and just use `@Valid` on the method argument (and don' tneed the `@Validated` on the class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I even tried that but that didn't work either. when I don't send notNull fields in request it says BadRequest but not throwing ConstraintViolationException which I am expecting in this case so that I can handle it and send custom message to client.

Comment: but I see org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'resourceRequest' on field 'clientId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.resourceRequest.clientId,NotNull.clientId,NotNull.java.lang.Integer,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [resourceRequest.clientId,clientId]; arguments []; default message [clientId]]; default message [clientId is required]]

Comment: It won't throw constraint exceptions and when doing validation like you are doing now it will result in http 500 errors. Also don't add additional information as comments as that is unreadable, edit your question instead. Using an object (which you really should) using `@NotNull` and `@NotBlank` should do exactly what you expect it to do, unless there is something you aren't showing us (or that this isn't the actual code that you are using but some dumbed down modified version)>